# Getting elements from a table and counting total

Tags: python

I have a table as such representing the result of a game.

```
GameTab = [['TRE','ARD','1','1'],['PRK','GEA','2','3'],['ARD','PRK','1','0'],['TRE','GEA','2','1']]
```

I appended the result from a text file into table form so here's the text format: To put it easier, it's interpreted in such that for example, TRE scored 1 and ARD scored 1. PRK scored 2 and GEA score 3.

```
TRE:ARD:1:1
PRK:GEA:2:3
ARD:PRK:1:0
TRE:GEA:2:1
```

Instead of obtaining the result for the player, i want to obtain the result of the opponent instead. I have done my code in a way where it obtains the result of the player but i couldn't think of a way to obtain the opponents result.

For example, in the match of PRK:GEA and TRE:GEA:

```
The opponent of GEA scored a total of: 4
```

My code:

```
gameTab =[['TRE','ARD','1','1'],['PRK','GEA','2','3'],['ARD','PRK','1','0'],
          ['TRE','GEA','2','1']]

dictionary = {}
for i in gameTab:
    for c in range(len(i[:2])):
        if i[:2][c] not in dictionary.keys():
               dictionary[i[:2][c]] = int(i[2:][c])
        else:
            dictionary[i[:2][c]] += int(i[2:][c])
print(dictionary)
```

Comment: have you tried using a pandas data-frame? (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#) It allows for very easy formatting of such tables. (see groupby http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to obtain the result of the opponent against a team, The below code satisfied the condition:

```
gameTab =[['TRE','ARD','1','1'],['PRK','GEA','2','3'],['ARD','PRK','1','0'],['TRE','GEA','2','1']]

dictionary = {}
for i in gameTab:
    if i[0] in dictionary:
    dictionary[i[0]] += int(i[3])
    else:
    dictionary[i[0]] = int(i[2])

    if i[1] in dictionary:
    dictionary[i[1]] += int(i[2])
    else:
    dictionary[i[1]] = int(i[2])

print(dictionary)
```

it prints out: `{'ARD': 1, 'GEA': 4, 'TRE': 2, 'PRK': 3}`

Basically traverse the list of lists, and for every team check if it exists in dictionary then increment its value as the opponents value. And finally you would get all point scored against a team by the opposition.

Answer (score 0):

```
gametab = [['TRE','ARD','1','1'],['PRK','GEA','2','3'],['ARD','PRK','1','0'],['TRE','GEA','2','1']]

dicta = {}
for i in range(len(gametab)):
    for j in range(2):
        if gametab[i][j] in dicta:
            dicta[gametab[i][j]] += int(gametab[i][j+2])
        else:
            dicta[gametab[i][j]] = int(gametab[i][j+2])

print dicta
```